# Doing Azure Container List with Shared Access signature and JQuery

Tags: jquery, azure, cors

I have added this rule:

```
    var corsRule = new CorsRule()
    {
        AllowedHeaders = new List<string> { "x-ms-*", "content-type", "accept" },
        AllowedMethods = CorsHttpMethods.Get | CorsHttpMethods.Options,//Since we'll only be calling Put Blob, let's just allow PUT verb
        AllowedOrigins = new List<string> { "https://localhost:44309" },//This is the URL of our application.
        MaxAgeInSeconds = 1 * 60 * 60,//Let the browswer cache it for an hour
    };
```

the console of chrome after doing

```
    $.ajax(sasUrl + '&comp=list', {
        type: 'GET',
        crossDomain: true,
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader('x-ms-blob-type', 'BlockBlob');
        },
    }).done((data) => console.log(data));
```

This is printet:

```
403 (Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.) 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://localhost:44309' is therefore not allowed access. 
 No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://localhost:44309' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try by getting rid of `x-ms-blob-type` request header in your request. So your ajax code should be:

```
$.ajax(sasUrl + '&comp=list', {
    type: 'GET',
    crossDomain: true,
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        //xhr.setRequestHeader('x-ms-blob-type', 'BlockBlob');
    },
}).done((data) => console.log(data));
```